# column select from transpose data in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi all i have date frame with columns name dates, the problem was i want to get the 4 weak form every column , so i try to transpose the date then i when columns become in rows so it will bw in one column i can select 4 weak from it ,
but when i transpose it the columns become rows but don’t add to data frame index data and i cant select it any more
i attach the picture for more clear view
any help for that, regards
[image]

firts image data frame before transpose

[image]
seconde image after transpose

Comment: i want to get 4 weak of month from every coulmn

Comment: no richie, it try to calclye month over month sales, the formula was get last sale week from every month and subtraction from previous weak , for example lase weak in month january was coulmn  1/26/19 and last weak in month february was 2/23/19  as you see in firts pic so i want to subtraction  2/23/19 coulmn sales with 1/26/19 and soo on to all data

Comment: what will happen with the 5th week of the months which have it?

Comment: yes you are right, so i try to trsnpose so i can do this formula to get only last weak from every month

Comment: from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
         

df['MonthEnd'] = df['Date'] + MonthEnd(1)
df[ (df['MonthEnd'] - df['Date']).dt.days <= 7 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not clear to me what you want to do with the 5th weeks, but this will get you the number for the week of the month.

```
# this will only work if the first date belongs to the first week of that month
# and if there is only one date per week
wom = ( # week of month
    df.index.to_series()
    .groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])
    .cumcount() + 1 # create the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 tags for week of month
)

# you can keep it as a separate indexer
sales_month_over = df.loc[wom < 5, :]


# or you can create a MultiIndex
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, wom], names=['date', 'wom'])
sales_month_over = df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('wom') < 5]
fifth_weeks = df.loc[~df.index.isin(sales_month_over.index)]

>>> print(sales_month_over)
                0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    ...  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114
date       wom                                          ...
2019-01-05 1     78  135   66   68   64   69  109   70  ...   58  166  122   81  162  193   74  196
2019-01-12 2    138  191  130   80  177   60  139  114  ...  147  188   59  149  126  131  133  178
2019-01-19 3    198  111  181  145   91   60  128  184  ...   80   54  110  152  114  165   86   68
2019-01-26 4    154  169  134   90  173  122  140  182  ...  186  140  150   65   68   92  128  169
2019-02-02 1    105   55   82   74  125  163   91   95  ...  199   67  116  155  128  162  133  110
...             ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
2020-05-23 4    163  176   92   78   88   64   55   79  ...  142  156  134  158   63  157   77   75
2020-06-06 1    133  167  117   91  180  106  169  154  ...   58  170  115  101  108   89   57   56
2020-06-13 2     78   86   93  192   53  143  182  184  ...  193  139   68  179   55   61  131  167
2020-06-20 3    119  123   91  145   71  193   97  182  ...  146  163   52  120  195   56  153  126
2020-06-27 4     50  191   72   89   76  151  166   89  ...  132   95  111  134   83   64  188  150

[72 rows x 115 columns]

>>> print(fifth_weeks)
                0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    ...  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114
date       wom                                          ...
2019-03-30 5    199  120  147   81   61   85  132  174  ...   99  162  177  104  118  168  117   92
2019-06-29 5    113   72   92   64  192  188   51  164  ...  143  137  126  117  162  157   53  102
2019-08-31 5    129  192   60  156  153  137  183  117  ...  155  115   57   92  124   99  143  119
2019-11-30 5    133  190  156  179   79  107  158  118  ...  165  180   91  139  176  159   61  103
2020-02-29 5    123  195  182  170  155  145  189   84  ...  152  115   74  128  190   72   53  104
2020-05-30 5    176  121  132  155   60   57  120  182  ...   57  136   52  190  152  168   65  164

[6 rows x 115 columns]
```

Now you can take the percentage change compared to the previous month

```
sales_month_over = sales_month_over.groupby(level='wom').pct_change()

>>> print(sales_month_over)
                     0         1         2         3    ...       111       112       113       114
date       wom                                          ...
2019-01-05 1         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-01-12 2         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-01-19 3         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-01-26 4         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-02-02 1   -0.063953 -0.259259 -0.259067 -0.401961  ...  0.084416  0.452055 -0.481250  0.012579
...                  ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
2020-05-23 4   -0.554878 -0.191860  0.285714  0.265734  ... -0.658824  0.943820  0.444444  0.950000
2020-06-06 1   -0.598540  1.763889 -0.155844 -0.338983  ... -0.248000 -0.006757 -0.512821 -0.043243
2020-06-13 2    0.130435  0.390244  0.423358 -0.460177  ... -0.013158 -0.167702  0.015385  0.305785
2020-06-20 3   -0.437500 -0.100000  1.650000  0.175439  ...  0.666667 -0.088235  0.155556  0.246753
2020-06-27 4    0.452055 -0.474820 -0.374269 -0.414365  ...  1.172414 -0.710983 -0.525641 -0.521368

[72 rows x 115 columns]
```

Comment: thanks it work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.index` to select the index column.